# Add a timeout for a command in fish shell on macOS

Tags: macos, timeout, fish

Is there a built-in timeout command with the fish shell on macOS?

I searched on Google and saw a `timeout` command for bash, but I got `fish: Unknown command: timeout` when I ran it.

Specifically, I would like to run a command (in this case `git status`) and add a timeout so that if it takes too long a different command is run. I was thinking of something like this pseudocode that would run `<cmd>` with a timeout of 500 milliseconds and instead run `<backup>` if `<cmd>` went over the time specified in `-t`:

```sh
$ # usage: timeout [-t <ms>] <cmd> [backup]
$ timeout -t 500 'git status' 'echo "took too long"'
```

Comment: Note that `timeout` is not a builtin in bash. It is an external comment that is typically installed on GNU Linux systems. On macOS you can install it via the HomeBrew package manager and use it from bash and fish scripts on macOS. You might want to run `type timeout` in the bash shell where it "works". You should see that it refers to an external command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timeout` is an ordinary command that works in any shell. If you are using Homebrew you can install it via `brew install coreutils`.

Comment: I installed coreutils, but running `timeout 0.01s git status` on a large repo where git status takes about a second doesn't do anything different from `git status`. I.e., timeout doesn't seem to interrupt Git. Why would this be? (Also, should I move this to a different question?)

Comment: I realized that I should post it as a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63211794/11588505