# Why does timeout not interrupt `git status` when it takes too long?

Tags: git, timeout, gnu-coreutils

Running `timeout 0.01s git status` on a large repo where `git status` takes about a second doesn't do anything different from `git status`. I.e., timeout doesn't seem to interrupt Git when it takes too long. Why would this be?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the timeout command simply sends a SIGTERM [signal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) whenever the timeout expires. This signal can be caught and ignored by processes, which would cause the process not to terminate. Git is probably ignoring the SIGTERM.

From the [timeout's manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html):

> If no signal is specified, send the TERM signal upon timeout.  The
> TERM signal kills any process that does not block or catch that
> signal. It may be necessary to use the KILL (9) signal (...)

If you **really** need it to timeout, you can use the `-k` switch to send a SIGKILL instead. **Use at your own risk.** This may or may not corrupt you repo:

```
timeout -k 0.02s 0.01s git status
```

This will first send a SIGTERM after 0.01s and then a SIGKILL after 0.02s of the first signal.

Note that you need to pass two durations (one for SIGTERM and one for SIGKILL).
I suggest you use a longer duration (e.g. 1s), otherwise git will probably not be able to do anything useful, depending on the size of your repo.

Comment: Is there no way to have Git obey the SIGTERM?